# Python syntax explanation need

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does the last method calling failed? What does parentheses do here?
I know everything is a object in Python, but I just want to get better knowledge about this.

```
$ python2.7
...
>>> (1).__add__(2)
3
>>> 1 .__add__(2)
3
>>> 1..__add__(2)
3.0
>>> 1.__add__(2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1.__add__(2)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number

```
1.
```

is considered a `float`. That's why

```
1..__add__(2)
```

returns `3.0` instead of just `3`. When you do

```
1.__add__(2)
```

it's like you did

```
1.0__add__(2)
```

which is not valid syntax.

**What does parentheses do here?** In this case, they are used to avoid that Python confused the dot `.` from the call to `__add__`  with the one from the float `1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `1.` starts a literal floating point number.